# How to get this in my GUI?

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

Thanks for looking at my question I hope you can bring me the awnsers I seek. I have tried a lot of diffrent ways. Maybe I just overlooked it. I am new to gui making etc.. Thanks for any input in advance

This is for the game Roblox that runs off of LUA

My question is...
Okay so I want this basic textbutton that closes the GUI from being open.
I can't figure it out lmfao maybe somebody can help me please?
I thought I had to make a new frame and put it where I wanted it and place the textbutton over it but nope. I've tried more ways and none worked.

```
-- Objects
local VanScreenGui = Instance.new("ScreenGui")
local OpenFrame = Instance.new("Frame")
local OpenTextButton = Instance.new("TextButton")
local VanGui = Instance.new("Frame")
local VanTextButton = Instance.new("TextButton")
local VanTextBox = Instance.new("TextBox")
local VanGuiCloser = Instance.new("TextButton")
local VanGuiCloserFrame = Instance.new("Frame")

-- Properties
VanScreenGui.Name = "VanScreenGui"
VanScreenGui.Parent = game.CoreGui
--
OpenFrame.Name = "OpenFrame"
OpenFrame.Parent = VanScreenGui
OpenFrame.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.new(1, 1, 1)
OpenFrame.Draggable = true
OpenFrame.Position = UDim2.new(0, 27, 0, 448)
OpenFrame.Size = UDim2.new(0, 76, 0, 29)
OpenFrame.Style = Enum.FrameStyle.DropShadow

OpenTextButton.Name = "Open.TextButton"
OpenTextButton.Parent = OpenFrame
OpenTextButton.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.new(1, 1, 1)
OpenTextButton.Position = UDim2.new(0, 6, 0, 0)
OpenTextButton.Size = UDim2.new(0, 50, 0, 15)
OpenTextButton.Style = Enum.ButtonStyle.RobloxRoundButton
OpenTextButton.Font = Enum.Font.SourceSans
OpenTextButton.FontSize = Enum.FontSize.Size14
OpenTextButton.Text = "OPEN"
OpenTextButton.TextSize = 14

VanGui.Name = "VanGui"
VanGui.Parent = VanScreenGui
VanGui.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.new(1, 1, 1)
VanGui.Draggable = true
VanGui.Position = UDim2.new(0, 33, 0, 343)
VanGui.Selectable = true
VanGui.Size = UDim2.new(0, 254, 0, 82)
VanGui.Style = Enum.FrameStyle.DropShadow
VanGui.Visible = false

VanTextButton.Name = "Van.TextButton"
VanTextButton.Parent = VanGui
VanTextButton.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.new(1, 1, 1)
VanTextButton.BackgroundTransparency = 0.5
VanTextButton.Position = UDim2.new(0, 30, 0, 41)
VanTextButton.Size = UDim2.new(0, 179, 0, 20)
VanTextButton.Font = Enum.Font.Arcade
VanTextButton.FontSize = Enum.FontSize.Size32
VanTextButton.Text = "VAN"
VanTextButton.TextSize = 30

VanTextBox.Name = "Van.TextBox"
VanTextBox.Parent = VanGui
VanTextBox.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.new(1, 1, 1)
VanTextBox.BackgroundTransparency = 0.5
VanTextBox.Position = UDim2.new(0, 32, 0, 0)
VanTextBox.Size = UDim2.new(0, 177, 0, 20)
VanTextBox.Font = Enum.Font.Arcade
VanTextBox.FontSize = Enum.FontSize.Size28
VanTextBox.Text = "name"
VanTextBox.TextSize = 25

VanGuiCloser.Name = "VanGuiCloser"
VanGuiCloser.Parent = VanGui
--VanGuiCloser.Visable = true
VanGuiCloser.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.new(1, 1, 1)
VanGuiCloser.BackgroundTransparency = 0.5
VanGuiCloser.Position = UDim2.new(0, 255, 0, 354)
VanGuiCloser.Size = UDim2.new(0, 20, 0, 14)
VanGuiCloser.Font = Enum.Font.SourceSans
VanGuiCloser.FontSize = Enum.FontSize.Size14
VanGuiCloser.Text = "X"
VanGuiCloser.TextSize = 14

OpenTextButton.MouseButton1Down:connect(function()
        game.CoreGui.VanScreenGui.VanGui.Visible = true
    game.CoreGui.VanScreenGui.OpenFrame.Visible = false
end)

VanGuiCloser.MouseButton1Down:connect(function()
        game.CoreGui.VanScreenGui.VanGui.Visible = false
    game.CoreGui.VanScreenGui.OpenFrame.Visible = true
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the open button then just use :Destroy()

Example

```
buttonname.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
game.CoreGui.openbuttonname:Destroy()
end)
```

If that is what you do not want to do, please be more clear, as it is hard to understand what you are saying.